# V8 engine is single threaded?

Tags: node.js

Since Node.js is single threaded and it's built over v8 engine of google chrome but the chrome has more then one thread.

Why we call it single threaded ?

Comment: @floor that link no more exists, can you please update.

Answer (score 5):

It's single threaded on the *JavaScript* side, but there are multiple threads under the hood of v8.

Comment: what  do the per thread do ? 
there are  11 theads  in d8, it is looks like  complex , T_T.

Comment: @jamlee - Garbage Collection, AFAIK

Answer (score 3):

> Since Node.js is single threaded

What makes you think so?

> but the chrome has more then one thread
>
> Why we call it single threaded ?

There are few misunderstandings here. First of all Chrome is a browser. It's not JavaScript, it can run multiple processes or threads or not. For example Chrome utilizes multiple threads when opening new tabs, spawning new, isolated JavaScript runtime each time.

Similarly Node.js is whole runtime environment, not only JavaScript. And as such it does utilize multiple threads for example for disk I/O.

But JavaScript itself is single-threaded (even though not guaranteed to be) in the sense that you can't access (directly) other threads from JavaScript itself. Yet.